# What is the correct way to say "business report" in French?

Tags: traduction

I found two options: "rapport d'entreprise" and "rapport de gestion". What is the difference between the two, and what is a better translation for "business report"?

Comment: *d'entreprise* would be a general term for any report done in a business, I think. *de gestion* would be a report of how the business was managed, following a similar structure to other things you could report on: *rapport d'affaires*, *rapport financier*, *rapport d'activité*. At least that's how I interpret it.

Comment: "Business report" itself is really vague. Do you have more context?

Comment: Well, all kinds of various ad hoc reports needed for departments inside a company... I need it in a pretty broad sense. So I guess "rapport d'entreprise" would be the one to use here?

Comment: Maybe "rapport d'activité" if it needs to be generic.

Comment: Thanks Frank, but doesn't "rapport d'entreprise" sound more generic than   "rapport d'activité"? Sorry I am being tedious, this is kinda important to me.

Comment: Well - Guillaume was saying below it doesn't really exist. And I think it would be misleading, as it feels like it could be an annual financial report for the whole company, but in your comment, you said it would be per department. "d'entreprise" would indicate it's for the whole company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rapport d'entreprise : ne s'emploie pas (le entreprise n'apporte rien)

**Rapport de gestion**: un peu réducteur. Il comprend souvent une partie financière (= rapport financier), une partie "ressources humaines" (= **rapport social**) et organisation.

On trouve également des **rapports *de recherche***, ...

L'ensemble, comprenant aussi l'activité (ventes, développement).

L'ensemble est souvent dénommé **rapport d'activité** , ou **rapport annuel**.

Answer (score 3):

Je pense que si c'est distribué dans  les différents départements et que c'est régulier,  par exemple tous les mois, on parle communément de 'tableaux de bord'

Comment: Bien intéressant ([FranceTerme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=tableau+de+bord&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search), [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=506873)) !

Answer (score 2):

Il semblerait que *rapport annuel* soit le terme le plus utilisé ([six fois plus que *rapport d'activité*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rapport%20d%27activit%C3%A9%2Crapport%20de%20gestion%2Crapport%20annuel&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Crapport%20d%20%27%20activit%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brapport%20d%20%27%20activit%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRapport%20d%20%27%20activit%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRapport%20d%20%27%20Activit%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRAPPORT%20D%20%27%20ACTIVIT%C3%89%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Crapport%20de%20gestion%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brapport%20de%20gestion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRapport%20de%20gestion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Crapport%20annuel%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brapport%20annuel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRapport%20annuel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRapport%20Annuel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRAPPORT%20ANNUEL%3B%2Cc0)) en français.

Par exemple, ce paragraphe provenant d'[Airliquide](https://www.airliquide.com/):

> In fact you will see that we are extremely precise in our business
>   report this year, in accordance with the recommendations of the [...]

est transcrit en français

> En effet, vous verrez que nous sommes extrêmement précis dans notre
>   Rapport annuel, conformément aux recommandations des différents
>   rapports ou réglementations.

Quoiqu'il en soit, les deux termes restent utilisés, et tout à fait compréhensibles. De mon expérience personnelle, j'entends également souvent les managers utiliser des anglicismes (business report, business plan, ... sont très en vogues).